# pygame installed in pycharm but still showing no module named pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I am on MacOS, trying to install pygame but keep getting a "No module named 'pygame'" error.

Started in terminal with

```
$ python3 -m pip install pygame
```

it reported error:

```
command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Some answers suggest pygame is incompatible with my current python version 3.8. So I installed python3.7.7 and installed pygame successfully. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDvBY.png)

Ran test with

```
$ python3 -m pygame.tests
```

Terminal shows `OK`. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJmpI.png)

I tried to run a project in pycharm and also `import pygram` in IDLE, both gave me error: `No module named 'pygame'`

Also tried to change project interpreter to python 3.7 in Pycharm and installed pygame in pycharm as well. Still getting the same error. [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT7E0.png)

I am not sure where went wrong. Appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: Inside pycharm terminal, what's the output of `python --version` and `python -m pip list | grep pygame`

Comment: PyCharm's default behavior for a new project is to create an empty virtual environment. Through PyCharm's settings GUI, either install pygame in the virtual environment, or change the current interpreter to your global Python 3.7.7.

Comment: @RMPR python version is 3.7.7. pip list returns pip 19.0.3, pygame 1.9.6, setuptools 40.8.0

Answer (score 0):

Now that you downgraded your python version, the gcc error isn't showing anymore?

You can try this:

```
pip install pygame==1.9.2
```

Also, I don't know if you checked this doc, but it's very helpful: https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

sys.path.append('your python file path /site-packages')

import pygame
```